# Variable printing with Integer values in Python

Tags: python, variables

Could anybody help with this python problem?

Problem:
-I need to print multiple variables times together when the variables have integer values.

If it helps i am trying to make a volume calculator and this is for context:

```
if(custom_answer is True and preset_answer is False):
    custom_length_answer=input("Length=")

    custom_width_answer=input("Width=")

    custom_height_answer=input("Height=")

a=custom_length_answer
b=custom_width_answer
c=custom_height_answer


while custom_answer is True and preset_answer is False:
    print("The volume of your custom measurements is..."int(a*b)*c)
```

Comment: "I need to print multiple variables times together when the variables have integer values."  I can't understand that sentence.

Comment: I am assuming that you are taking three variables (length, width and height) and you are taking them to calculate the volume of the prism. Is that right? Can you tell us what you would like ideally for your output? Also, at the end, what is your loop used for?

Comment: I need to be able to print the variables when they have an integer value but instead of just printing the variable and it showing the number that the variable holds, i would like to be able to use the variables in a sum to give an outcome.

Comment: Yes that is what i would like @Zizouz212 and the loop is for a bit of the code before that i did not include, it just varies on what the user previously wanted so its uneeded for the solution im asking

Comment: So you want to return the variables that the user inputed, and you want to use the variables in a sum (your code shows a product in a while loop). Is that correct?

Comment: I'm also assuming that you need to make sure that the variables are integers. Right?

Comment: Also for an ideal output i would want the volume which would be calculated by the 3 user inputs (length,, width and height)

Comment: Yes i also need to make sure the variable are integers

Comment: I think that covers all the context needed so if anybody can come up with a solution and help me i would be appreciative of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! So I am assuming that:

1. You need the variables to be integers
2. You need to calculate the volume in a while loop
3. You want to return the variables that the user had inputted.
4. I'm also assuming that you are using python 2

This is what your code should look like:

```
if (custom_answer == True and preset_answer == False):
    custom_length_answer = a = int(raw_input("Length= ") # assign variable to a and assuring that it is already an integer using the int.
    custom_length_answer = b = int(raw_input("Width= ") # Same as above
    custom_length_answer = c = int(raw_input("Height= ") # Same as above

return a # returning the value of the variables
return b
return c

while custom_answer == True and preset_answer == False: # Your loop
    print("The volume of your custom measurements is:" + a*b*c)
    # some more code
```

Hopefully this helps! :)